# Smarty include passing array in var

Tags: php, smarty

I try to pass an array element in include's var.

But I still have this error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty Compiler: Syntax error in template "file:/home/technique/www/site/tpl/home.html" on line 6 "{include file='include/article-latest.html' class='col-50' title=$article.TITLE tag=ARTICLE_CATEGORY.$article.CATEGORY img=$article.THUMBNAIL view='3526' share='564'}" - Unexpected ".", expected one of: "}" <-- thrown in /home/technique/www/common/lib/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php on line 6

My code :

```
{foreach $latest_article.0 as $article}
    {include file='include/article-latest.html' class='col-50' title=$article.TITLE tag=ARTICLE_CATEGORY.$article.CATEGORY img=$article.THUMBNAIL view='3526' share='564'}
{/foreach}
```

Apparently, the problem is using the constant ARTICLE_CATEGORY. It seem like the php constant isn't interpreted by smarty...

Comment: To access PHP constants in Smarty, you can use {$smarty.const.MY_CONSTANT} which is https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.variables.smarty.tpl#language.variables.smarty.const

Answer (score 1):

PHP constants in Smarty can be called by $smarty.const.CONSTANT_NAME
Reference is here - https://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?p=25903&sid=92c2eb2c177f8f82ae084361ee6c4400

```
{foreach $latest_article.0 as $article}
    {include file='include/article-latest.html' class='col-50' title=$article.TITLE tag=$smarty.const.ARTICLE_CATEGORY.$article.CATEGORY img=$article.THUMBNAIL view='3526' share='564'}
{/foreach}
```

besides take into account the following:
- TITLE and CATEGORY might be constants in the code too therefore must be called via $smarty.const.TITLE and $smarty.const.CATEGORY appropriately;
- ARTICLE_CATEGORY is constant so it is strange that it is used as array;
- ARTICLE.$article.CATEGORY might be too deep-level array and might be processed by Smarty incorrectly (because of too many dots). To fix it, you might need to assign variables, for example:

```
{assign var="article_category" value=$smarty.const.ARTICLE_CATEGORY}
{foreach $latest_article.0 as $article}
    {include file='include/article-latest.html' class='col-50' title=$article.TITLE tag=$article_category.$article.CATEGORY img=$article.THUMBNAIL view='3526' share='564'}
{/foreach}
```